# Focus shifts to scrollbars after navigating to first/last item in WPF ListView when horizontal scrollbar is visible

Tags: wpf, listview, keyboard, navigation, scrollbar

I have a WPF ListView where using the Up/Down keys I want the selected item (row) to move up/down. This generally works fine.

However, when a horizontal scrollbar appears on the ListView and I move Up to the first (top) row, or the last (bottom) row focus then shifts to the scrollbars, so that when I then use the Up/Down or Left/Right keys the vertical and horizontal scrollbars move. The selected item does not change, only the scrollbar moves.

I want the Up/Down keys to always move the selected item/row. If the first row is reached, the focus should remain on the selected item (row) and not move to the scrollbars, so that when I then press the Down key the focus will move to the 2nd row. If he last row is reached, the focus should remain on the last row and when Up key is pressed, the 2nd to last row should get focus.

This works the way I want when the horizontal scrollbar is not visible, even if the vertical scrollbar is visible. But, when both scrollbars are visible the focus shifts to the scrollbars, when after reaching first or last row the Up/Down keys affect the scrollbars as described above.

How can I fix this, so that the Up/Down keys always affect the selected row and does NOT affect the scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322506/how-to-stop-cursor-to-move-outside-from-the-listview-on-pressing-down-key-if-i

Comment: @Elan - Its working fine for me! Can you post some sample code which is not working along with this?